# ASP NET EF Select Distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Amigos estoy tratando de hacer un

> Select Distinct years from HomeInfoFinanciera

Pero no lo consigo, este es el método que estoy usando para hacer el query.

```
    public JsonResult JSONInfoFinYears()
    {
        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {              
            var infofin = db.HomeInfoFinanciera.Select(m => m.year).Distinct(); 
            return Json(infofin, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Este es el query que me genera

```
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[year] AS [year]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent1].[year] AS [year]
    FROM [dbo].[HomeInfoFinanciera] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

ejecutando este query me devuelve lo que quiero la lista de años, pero me da error en la respuesta del método.

este es mi error

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Comment: Cual es el error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso pasa porque los datos todavía no se han consultado, solo se ha generado la consulta. 
`var infofin = db.HomeInfoFinanciera.Select(m => m.year).Distinct()`
Entonces cuando se intentan consultar los datos el dbcontext ya se ha cerrado.`return Json(infofin, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`. Para evitar que eso pase primero realiza la consulta llamando al método ToList() `var infofin = db.HomeInfoFinanciera.Select(m => m.year).Distinct().ToList();`

```
 public JsonResult JSONInfoFinYears()
    {
        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {              
            var infofin = db.HomeInfoFinanciera.Select(m => m.year).Distinct().ToList(); 
            return Json(infofin, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias que tonto que deje pasar convertirlo en lista cuando todo asp es una lista, mil gracias